# Dapper return data type DATE with time

Tags: c#, date, datetime, formatting

I have problem. I have MySQL database and I use DATE type for my date column. I want to save date without time only.
In database date is saved like this 06/02/1999 for example.
But when I try to take it with dapper

```cs
var test = connection.QueryFirstAsync<string>(@"SELECT BirthDate FROM Students");
```

Then it returns `06/02/1999 00:00:00`
How can I fix that? I want string without that time that shouldn't even be there in first place.
Thank you very much for answers

Comment: You could have more control of how you returned the date format if you did not return it as a string, e.g. you could do `connection.QueryFirstAsync<DateTime>()` instead and then choose your format while using the `ToString()` method.

Comment: I shortened my code. I use Student model object in dapper parameter. Which contains string for date. But I will probably rewrite it for DateTime like you are saying. Thanks

Comment: Specifically, you can use `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` with @Jacob's approach (or flip the MM and dd if needed. I made an assumption with your format).

Comment: Dapper knows date format of mySQL I suppose? So I don't have to deal with it somehow

Comment: *"date is saved like this 06/02/1999"* - If you're using the `DATE` type, that's incorrect. That's just a rendering of the value in a format that you can understand. `DATE` is stored in binary form, as it should be. You're confusing the value with its representation. When you need to display it, convert it to a string in the expected format, but getting it from the database as a `DateTime` with a zero time component is not something you need to "fix".

Comment: "I want string without that time that shouldn't even be there in first place" A `DateTime` always has a time component, you just need to render it using `ToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple (maybe naive) solution is this one:

```
string date = "06/02/1999 00:00:00";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
DateOnly dateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime);
```

Note: `DateOnly` applies to .NET 6, .NET 7 Preview 6

Comment: Thank you, I will rewrite my app to use DateTime for date. Not strings

Comment: Just note that `DateOnly` is not going to be available for older versions, such as .NET Framework 4.8 or .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yes right.. I will update my answer to include this info, thanks

Comment: @SPIRINN BrootsWaymb refered to `DateOnly` struct

Comment: Yes, I missread it sorry